# How to keep the focus on one form while opening other?

Tags: c#, forms

I have form that takes few seconds to load and open,
i need the other form (Form Represents "Please Wait ...") to be focused and stable while opening the main form.

I close the please wait form after 2 secs BUT it doesn't take the general focus.

This is the code i use to open the two forms :

```
        LoadingPage load = new LoadingPage();
        load.Show();

        load.TopMost = true;

        //
        string contractorType = "importer";

        //
        customersPage obj = new customersPage(this, contractorType);
        obj.MdiParent = homeObj;
        obj.Show();
```

Please, any idea ?

thanks,

Comment: yes sir, but it doesn't work as i want so i tried to use **TopMost** property but it seems to give the same result here !

Comment: You also need to show the code which executes after 2 secs.

Comment: i have nothing to show else .. the form is loaded and i need to show loading until the form is opened.

Answer (score 1):

That may be behaving funny because `customerPage` is an MDI child.  Have you considered making `LoadingPage` modal?  You would of course have to load your `customerPage` from events within `LoadingPage` (e.g. `Form_Load` or a 100ms timer callback, etc.,) because the call to `ShowModal` will block until `LoadingPage` closes.

The idea is that if `LoadingPage` is modal, then no other window in the same thread can take focus from it.

Comment: it's a good trick !
but it doesn't work correctly and seems to be overlaped with the main form.